# running the first example of playframework in IntelliJ on a Mac OSX

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea

In my new mac OSX 10.8.3,
I install scala 2.10.0, play 2.1.0 and IntelliJ12,
and create a play project as follows:

```
#install brew
> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
> brew --version
0.9.4

# update brew database
> cd $(brew --prefix)
> brew update
> cd $(brew --prefix) && git pull --rebase

# get scala 2.10.0
> brew versions scala
2.10.1   git checkout 79dc6f1 Library/Formula/scala.rb
2.10.0   git checkout 8ca07aa Library/Formula/scala.rb
2.9.2    git checkout 8896425 Library/Formula/scala.rb
...

> git checkout 8ca07aa Library/Formula/scala.rb   # 2.10.0
> brew install scala
> scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.0 -- Copyright 2002-2012, LAMP/EPFL


# install play 2.1.0
> brew versions play
2.1.0    git checkout 6a70797 Library/Formula/play.rb
...

> brew install play
> play -version
play! 2.1.0 (using Java 1.6.0_43 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org
```

and I create a play application:

```
> cd ~/
> play new myapp
name: myapp
Create a simple Scala application

# generate IntelliJ project:
> cd myapp
> play
> idea
[info] Created /Users/david/myapp/.idea_modules/myapp.iml
[info] Created /Users/david/myapp/.idea_modules/myapp-build.iml
```

and open the project in IntelliJ:

```
# Install IntelliJ 12 Ultimate Edition
Download it from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/
12.0.4, Build #IU-123.169
Build on February 13, 2013

# install scala plugin in IntelliJ
run IntelliJ,
Preferences -> plugins -> Browse from repositories -> add scala.
current version: 0.7.134

# open myapp project in IntelliJ
File -> Open Project, chose the directory /Users/david/myapp
```

Then when I try to run the unit test:

```
Project -> myapp -> test -> ApplicationSpec -> (right click) -> Run
```

I get this error:

```
scala: Сompiler library for module bigbrother not found: Right(Project) / Right(scala-2.10.0)
```

Actually, there are several errors:

```
in File -> Project Structure -> Modules, there are two modules:
-myapp
-mypp-build

File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> myapp -> Scala
   Compiler library: scala-2.10.0 [not found]
   <<< ERROR

File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> myapp-build -> Dependencies:
   scala-2.9.2
   <<< ERROR
```

If I correct the first error as follows,

```
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> myapp -> Scala -> Compiler library
and from the dropdown list I select the second valid option “scala-2.10.0 (version 2.10.0)”.
```

Then, re-running the test, produces the error:

```
scala: Output path /Users/david/bigbrother/project/target/scala_2.9.2 is shared between: Module 'bigbrother-build' production, Module 'bigbrother-build' tests
Currently external Scala compiler prohibits output path sharing.
Either disable the external build mode or configure separate output paths.
TIP: you can use Project Artifacts to combine compiled classes.
```

What do I need to do to make it work?

---

**Update: solution based on the answers from Marius and alexwriteshere**

generate IntelliJ project with

```
> cd myapp
> play
> idea no-sbt-build-module
```

(instead of just 'idea')

then,
Project Settings -> Libraries
Select "Scala 2.9.2" and click on "-" to remove it.

then,
Project Settings -> Module -> my_app -> Scala -> Scala-compiler
in this dropdown list, there is selected "Scala 2.10.0" written in red.
move to the top of the list, and select "Scala 2.10.0 (version 2.10.0)" written in black/grey.

---

**Note**

sometimes (I don't know why) the choice "Scala 2.10.0 (version 2.10.0)" written in black/grey is not available in the dropdown list.
a workaround that works for me to make it available is as follows:
Project Settings -> Global Libraries -> + -> Java
select these files scala-compiler.jar, scala-library.jar and scala-reflect.jar from this directory: /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.0/libexec/lib/
select Ok.
Give it the name "my scala 2.10.0 bundle".

then, go again to Project Settings -> Module -> my_app -> Scala -> Scala-compiler
now you have both, the one you just created "my scala 2.10.0 bundle", and the standard one: "Scala 2.10.0 (version 2.10.0)" written in black/grey. select the standard one, and delete the global library you created.

I don't know why this happens, and I really don't want to spend more time finding this out. for the moment, this workaround works for me. but feel free to add a comment if you find out.

Comment: Awesome! IDEA still marks some statement as wrong for me, even if everything compiles. But at least not everything is red.

Comment: I re-imported project from maven (what has worked for me)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problems can be solved by generating the idea project with:

```
$ play  # start play from command line
[your-play-project] $ idea no-sbt-build-module
```

This will enable IntelliJ's default building mechanism for Scala, which won't cause these problems.

Comment: Worked great for me! As a side note, I had been using `sbt` and `play` interchangeably at the command line. After running this I had trouble with `sbt` (likely expected) so ensure that you continue to use `play` after making this change.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what helped me in the past with the same errors:

1. Remove any Scala 2.9.2 dependencies
2. Go to `Project Structure -> Global libraries`. Create a new one, called, say, `scala-bundle`. Add scala-compiler.jar, scala-library.jar, scala-reflect.jar for 2.10.
3. Finally, go to `Project Structure -> Modules -> myapp -> Scala` and select `scala-bundle`.

For module sharing errors, go to `Project Structure -> Modules -> <each module> -> Paths` and change the paths so they're not the same.

Comment: i did as Marius said (play idea no-sbt-build-module), plus removed scala 2.9.2 dependencies, are updated with the module with the scala 2.10.0 that intellij found (instead of the not-found generated by play idea). i would mark both questions as answers, but stackoverflow does not allow this.