# coursera, "Functional Programming Principles in Scala", Setting up IntelliJ on OSX

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

The "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" coursera is prepared for Eclipse.

Here there is a tutorial about using IntelliJ instead of Eclipse for the course:
http://www.guardian.co.uk/info/developer-blog/2012/sep/21/funtional-programming-principles-scala-setting-up-intellij

However, it fails with:

```
sbt
gen-idea
[error] Not a valid command: gen-idea
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: gen-idea
[error] gen-idea
[error]         ^
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: do you have [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error it looks like you don't have the sbt intellij plugin installed. 
You need to add this depencency to your sbt config :

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.3.0")

You can add this line to YOUR_PROJECT/project/plugins.sbt - that will work but you will have to do it for each project (note that you might have to create plugins.sbt).

A more convenient way : add the dependency in ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt - that way, the plugin will be available each time you start sbt, regardless of the project specific config.

Answer (score 0):

Install scala 2.10.0 and IntelliJ as in:
[running the first example of playframework in IntelliJ on a Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751139/running-the-first-example-of-playframework-in-intellij-on-a-mac-osx)

If you are using the scala playframework,
then temporally clean ivy2 ([because there is a namespace collision with sbt-idea and playframework](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbt-idea/pull/1))

```
rm -rf ~/.ivy2
```

Do as described in:

https://class.coursera.org/progfun-002/forum/thread?thread_id=9&post_id=24#post-24

http://www.guardian.co.uk/info/developer-blog/2012/sep/21/funtional-programming-principles-scala-setting-up-intellij

except that:

- the file ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt should contain:

  addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0")
- use scala 2.10.0 instead of scala 2.9.2

then it works, at least for me.